# Website where you can find Ordered Lists of Items?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know there are many libraries for League of Legends Items but I still haven't found one that allows you to sort Items for a particular stat category (ascending or descending).

Lets say for example that I want all items giving Ability Power Descending (starting from the one giving the most and ending with the one giving the least).

Or do the same with Health or Attack Damage.

I think you get the point. It would be a really useful tool. And none of the known wikis-libraries offers this feature.

I have tried those:

- http://na.leagueoflegends.com/items
- [leaguecraft.com/items/](http://leaguecraft.com/items/)
- [leagueoflegends.wikia.com](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com)

Comment: Indeed, I can't find such thing on the usual guide ones either (lolking, solomid, mobafire...). It could be useful.

Comment: @Gnoupi Now that I think about it, I find it weird that you don't even have this option in Game (Shop).

Comment: The problem with such a list are items with passives that are dependant on other stats, for example Atma's Impaler that gives AD depending on the Health of the wearer, making it impossible to properly sort or judge it without the proper context.

Comment: @dbemerlin True but I would be satisfied with just the flat Stat Order. Maybe Highlighting such items adding a note stating that it may increase depending on something.

Comment: there are apps that do this... beyond that I'm not sure what to say about it

Comment: @Ender Can you point to a particular app that does it please?

Comment: Here is someone's attempt at this, although it's incomplete at the moment, and I'm not sure if he's updating any more. http://lol.darwin.com.pl/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this link](http://s3.microtony.com/) can help you. It is a item shop Simulator.

I think it is not official, but it really helps me when I want to find some item in the shop, without having to create a custom game.

Comment: This is nice...But it's a shop Simulator which means it doesn't really have the functionality I'm looking for (ordering items by a particular attribute)

Comment: You can use the search filters in the "All Items" section. This way you can see the items with the same attribute, ordered by price.

Comment: Yeah the price ordering is useful but if you want to get one category (e.g. Items with Health) ordered by Health so you can find out the one that gives you the most flat health faster you can't do that. For example the Most expensive item in Health Items is Trinity Force which is not the item that you would want to find when you are looking at the top of that list. You'd expect to find Warmogs for example.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I dont know any item list like that. Hope someone find the simulator useful at least. =)